# React router don't change UI

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem with "react-router-dom" when I call a route it doesn't change my view

```
<div>
<Switch>
    <Route path="/">
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell align="left">Nome</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="left">Data Inizio</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="left">Data Fine</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="center">
                            <Tooltip title="AGGIUNGI">
                                <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="modifica" component={Link}
                                            to={`${url}/add`}
                                            style={{float: "left"}}>
                                    <AddRounded/>
                                </IconButton>
                            </Tooltip>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                   [..]
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    </Route>
    <Route path={`${path}/add`} ><h1>TEST</h1></Route>
</Switch>
```

```
    const {url, path} = useRouteMatch();
```

Anyone have any idea why it doesn't work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your useRouteMatch() hook used?

Comment: At the top of the function

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this does not work is, it'll change the routing dynamically as you click on `IconButton`.
When you are in the base route "/" initially, you'll get the following button,

```
<IconButton color="primary" aria-label="modifica" component={Link}
                                        to={`${url}/add`}
                                        style={{float: "left"}}>
```

and as you click on it, will generate the URL like `'//add'`.
since at the base route `url` will be empty string.

This will give an error since it's an invalid route.

Simply you might use the following route (if required),

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Link to={`/add`}> To add</Link>
      </Route>
      <Route exact path={`/add`}>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```